# Is this radio communicating creature viable? (Volutus sapiens)

Tags: creature-design, communication

I have already reviewed a few questions about the feasibility of a radio communicating creature. Like these:

- [How would organic EM transmitters/recievers be different than our mechanical ones](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/how-would-organic-em-transmitters-recievers-be-different-than-our-mechanical-one)
- [Anatomically correct radio communication](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123462/anatomically-correct-radio-communication/123511#123511)

But this is a different particular case. I have this creature I am designing (*Volutus sapiens*). It is basically a meat roll (literally).
[image]

They live on an Earth-like planet and they are carbon-based.
Besides their standard circulatory system, they have a secondary circulatory conduit of ferromagnetic fluid.
To communicate, they use their muscles along that conduit to move a bulge of ferromagnetic fluid in circles (as shown in the second picture). The creatures can move the fluid at will, altering the speed and rotation pattern as they wish.
[image]

And they receive the electromagnetic signals through a circular nervous system with a high concentration of iron to make it more sensible to the electromagnetic signals. (third image).

[image]

the question is: **Is this specific way of radiocommunication possible?**

Comment: *Tortamque*? What is *tortamque* supposed to mean? It surely does not look like a Latin (or Latinised Greek) noun in the nominative singular. (Would the word be actual Latin it would mean "and bent/turned/wound" feminine accusative singular.)

Comment: According to https://translate.google.com/#la/en/Tortamque  "Tortamque" is latin, and it means "roll".

Comment: Google Translate is wrong. If you mean "a roll of bread", you may try *Collix*, *Collyra*, *Collyris* (all three words are Greek, but at least [*collyris*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcollyris) was used in Latin). In you mean "someting rolled up", you may want something with "-voluta" or "-volutus" (e.g., *Pervoluta*, *Supervolutus*) (from [*volvo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dvolvo), to roll). If you mean "a scroll", then *volumen* (e.g., *Involumen*).

Comment: Google Translate *might* have seen *tortamque* in a Latin text, where the English translation has "rolled" or "roll", but Google Translate is too simple minded to know that languages actually have grammars. The *-am-* part means "1st declension (usu. feminine) accusative, singular"; the *-que* means "and", as in "senatus populusque", the senate *and* the people. In [New Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Latin) (used as an international language during the Renaissance and Early Modern period), *torta* does indeed mean "a pie, a tart, a flat cake"; but the *-amque* is definitely wrong.

Comment: I would think there are easier ways to achieve this , by looking at a how produces electric current based on electroplaque cells basically resembling a voltaic pile. You could have some kind of iron based rings around the body caused by depositing blood clots. The interference of the electric field with iron should produce a electro magnetic field ?. However you will need some way to convince that this kind of communication is preferably from an evolution stand point to air waves based communication.

Comment: @AlexP Thank you Alex. I have changed the name from "Tortamque sapiens" to "Volutus sapiens".

Comment: @AlexP that reminds me of a scene from *The Life of Brian*.

Comment: @Renan: Quite unintentional, I assure you. *Ferrivoluti communicate undis electromagneticis!*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling around a ferromagnetic fluid I think it would be more effective for the organism to utilize triboluminescence or piezoluminescence to produce electromagnetic radiation. These are physical/chemical processes that are already at work in existing lifeforms.

The receptive organ would essentially be an eye that was sensitive to whatever frequency the sending organ produces. Since radio frequencies are more penetrative than light the receptive organ could be safely internalized (an eye on the inside).

If the receptor and sending organs were combined in the same structure this organism could utilize back scattering to see in total darkness.

Answer (score 0):

### I don't think so.

A conductive loop must move within a magnetic field, or vice versa, to create a current, which is needed to create radio waves.

In *Tortamque sapiens*, though, as is currently constructed, the conductive loop **is** the magnetic field.

Comment: Moving through a magnetic field and having an alterating field have an the exact same effect -U = dPhi/dt = d/dt (B * S); U being the induced Voltage, Phi being the magnetic flux, B being the magnetic field density and S the surface area (and t being time, of course). So alteration of B ***OR*** S cause Induction.